# Deploy webapp on GAE then do changes online from GAE console

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I deployed a webapp2 python application on GAE. Is there any way with which i can explore the source code or make changes in the project files from GAE console. Is it possible that if i only want to update a single .py file on already deployed app rather than again deploying the whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this :

https://console.cloud.google.com/code/develop

I pushed my code on Google Cloud Platform with git, and I'm able to change text files directly online.

The doc is here :
https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/