# Where are source files stored on Google Cloud Platform when deployed from local machine

Tags: node.js, linux, google-app-engine, express, terminal

I have just deployed the basic NodeJS express app on Google Cloud Platform from IntelliJ IDEA. However I cannot find and browse the source files. I have searched in the Development tab, App Engine tab and it shows the project but not the actual files. I can access the application from my browser and it is running fine. I can see the activity and requests everything coming into the application but I cannot see the source files. I tried searching for them in the terminal Google Cloud Console and I cannot locate the files in there either. It's puzzling because I don't know where the files are being served from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK seeing the live app code/static content directly in the developer console is not possible (at least not yet), not even for the standard environment apps.

For apps using the flexible environment (that includes node.js apps) accessing the live app source code may be even more complex as what's actually executed on GAE is a container image/docker file (as opposed to plain app code source file from a standard environment app). From [Deploying your program](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_your_program):

> Deploy your app using the [gcloud app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) command. This command
>   automatically builds a container image for you by using the [Container
>   Builder](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/) service (Beta) before deploying the image to the App
>   Engine flexible environment control plane. The container will include
>   any local modifications you've made to the runtime image.

Since the container images are fundamentally dockerfiles it might be possible to extract their content using the [docker export](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) command:

> ```
> Usage:  docker export [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
>
> Export a container's filesystem as a tar archive
>
> Options:
>       --help            Print usage
>   -o, --output string   Write to a file, instead of STDOUT
> ```
>
> The `docker export` command does not export the contents of volumes
>   associated with the container. If a volume is mounted on top of an
>   existing directory in the container, `docker export` will export the
>   contents of the *underlying* directory, not the contents of the
>   volume.

One way of checking the exact structure of the deployed app (at least in the standard environment) is to download the app code and check it locally - may be useful if suspected incorrect app deployment puts a question mark on the local app development repository from where deployment originated. Not sure if this is possible with the flexible environment, tho.

The accepted answer to the recent [Deploy webapp on GAE then do changes online from GAE console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316090/deploy-webapp-on-gae-then-do-changes-online-from-gae-console) post appears to indicate that reading and maybe even modifying live app code might be possible (but I didn't try it myself and it's not clear if it would also work for the flexible environment).